# What is this toilet flush mechanism called?

Tags: repair, toilet

I need to replace the flush handle on this toilet, but I don't know what the mechanism is called, and I couldn't find a handle that fit it at Home Depot. What is it called, and/or where can I find a replacement for the flush handle with a + at the end?
[image: flush]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Next by Danco FLT231T HydroStop Flapper Alternative](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BQK1EDK)

I've put these in all my toilets and they work great. I'm not sure about getting just the handle for it, but now you know what to look for. Try [danco.com](http://www.danco.com)

Comment: Amazon comments indicate that people haven't had success finding replacement parts... but for $11 I'll buy a new whole thing and salvage the flusher.